# How to replace values in entire column

Tags: r, dataframe

```
          SNP    CHR       BP         P
1 rs149201999      1 16050408 0.0654584
2 rs146752890 489381 16050612 0.1019340
3 rs139377059      3 16050678 0.0639282
```

Wanted to learn how to replace the CHR with the number 22 in each of the rows.

```
test <- replace(df$CHR, df$CHR==22, length=nrow(df))
```

Comment: `df$CHR <- "22"` or `df$CHR <- as.numeric("22")`

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to do

```
df$CHR <- 22
```

That replaces all the values in the CHR column.

Although the `replace` function would work as well you'd have to use it like this

```
replace(df$CHR, values = rep(x = 22, length(df$CHR)))
```

It is overkill in this case though.